# Complex Table with Rowspan Hover and Zebra effect

Tags: css, hover, css-tables

I'm trying to make a hover effect for a table with multiple rowspan but I don't manage to make it fully work.

The css as described in another stackoverflow is not working (see solution here https://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/KqoCs ).

The example here (rowspan on multiple columns) : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rJXgzW

The hover css effect is defined as :

```
tbody:hover td[rowspan], tr:hover td {
   background: red; 
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The trick in the working example is to use multiple `<tbody>` elements in the table where each table body contains *one* table cell spanning multiple rows. That way

```
tbody:hover td[rowspan] { background: red; }
```

makes it magically appear as requested. This doesn't work with the second example in the same way, as there are (1) multiple row-spanning elements and (2) it's using `<th>` elements (which is easy to address, though).

To get it working using CSS only, you would need to nest tables inside table cells.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I don't mark this as ok as maybe in the future a solution will be available.

Comment: It will in some cases be possible once CSS includes a parent selector. The Selector Level 4 Specs include the `:has` pseudo class which could be used, e.g. like `tr:has(> td:hover) td[rowspan]`, but it is not supported yet by any browser, see/follow https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has for more information/updates.

Answer (score 0):

sharing the vanilla JS I wrote specifically for this case, it works on the [complex codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rJXgzW), just add `.u-table-hover` to the CSS hover rule (`tr:hover th , tr:hover td` to `tr:hover th , tr:hover td, .u-table-hover`) and paste the script.

This can probably be more compact, any suggestion is welcome.

```js
function initTableHover() {

    /**
     * Mouse events only on tables with rowspan cells
     */
    document.querySelectorAll('td[rowspan], th[rowspan]').forEach(function (cellRowspan) {
        // Only match on tbody elements, you may extend this to thead
        cellRowspan.closest('table').querySelectorAll('tbody td, tbody th').forEach(function (tableCell) {
            tableCell.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
                let parentTr = tableCell.closest('tr');
                if (parentTr) {
                    let trPreviousSibling = parentTr.previousElementSibling;
                    let previousSiblingDistance = 1;
                    // previousSiblingDistance < 100 probably useless, just a safety
                    while (null !== trPreviousSibling && previousSiblingDistance < 100) {
                        trPreviousSibling.querySelectorAll('td[rowspan], th[rowspan]').forEach(function (cellRowspan) {
                            if (cellRowspan.getAttribute('rowspan') > previousSiblingDistance) {
                                /**
                                  * You can change the hover class here
                                  * This class is added to the cell with the rowspan attribute
                                  */
                                cellRowspan.classList.add('u-table-hover'); 
                            }
                        });
                        trPreviousSibling = trPreviousSibling.previousElementSibling;
                        previousSiblingDistance++;
                    }
                }
            });

            /**
              * Remove the class anywhere, should be fine
              */
            tableCell.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
                tableCell.closest('tbody').querySelectorAll('.u-table-hover').forEach(function (tableElement) {
                    tableElement.classList.remove('u-table-hover');
                })
            });
        });
    });
}

if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
    initTableHover();
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initTableHover);
}
```